# Emacs ruby-mode how to prevent narrowed buffer from widening when manual save is triggered

Tags: terminal-emacs, narrowing, ruby-mode, save

I just discovered [narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) in Emacs, and it's great to be able to focus on a single function or block of code.

However, after I narrow with `C-x n n`, make some changes and then save manually with `C-x C-s` the buffer widens again **while I am in Ruby mode**.

How do I prevent save from triggering widening? (I can see how it's handy, but I'd like to turn it off for now.)

Thank you StackExchange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried [ `(remove-hook 'after-save-hook 'ruby-mode-set-encoding)` ],
> but it didn't work since, I think, the hook is buffer local?

Both `add-hook` and `remove-hook` have a LOCAL argument for modifying
the buffer-local hook value.  If that's how it's added, that's also
how you can remove it (most likely via `ruby-mode-hook`).

And indeed if we look at `ruby-mode` itself this is exactly the case:

```el
(define-derived-mode ruby-mode prog-mode "Ruby"
[...]
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'ruby-mode-set-encoding nil 'local)
  (add-hook 'electric-indent-functions #'ruby--electric-indent-p nil 'local)
  (add-hook 'flymake-diagnostic-functions #'ruby-flymake-auto nil 'local)
```

So you would then do this:

```el
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook #'my-ruby-mode-hook)

(defun my-ruby-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `ruby-mode' behaviours."
  (remove-hook 'after-save-hook #'ruby-mode-set-encoding 'local))
```

That said, I imagine `ruby-mode-set-encoding` is doing something useful, and you probably don't actually want to inhibit that.

This looks to me like a bug in `ruby-mode-set-encoding`.  You should <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug` to suggest that `save-restriction` is used in that function.  Maybe there's something else going on which needs the widening to happen, but if not then it seems like an easy fix.

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks you @phils. I think they do use save-restriction in that code, but the issue persists so I'll report it. Thanks for teaching me how to report it.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually traced this to `ruby-mode-set-encoding` in `ruby-mode.el`.

**I worked around it with the following in my `.emacs`:**

```
(with-eval-after-load 'ruby-mode 
  (defun ruby-mode-set-encoding () "override the default" ()))
```

It's a terrible hack, but it allows me to move on with my daily work and I can disable it occasionally to make sure magic comments are still present.

I also tried this, but it didn't work since, I think, the hook is buffer local?

```
(with-eval-after-load 'ruby-mode
  (remove-hook 'after-save-hook 'ruby-mode-set-encoding))
```

Open to ideas on how to fix this right, but thought I'd leave something for anyone who stumbles across this issue.

Comment: Both `add-hook` and `remove-hook` have a LOCAL argument for modifying the buffer-local hook value.  If that's how it's added, that's also how you can remove it (most likely via `ruby-mode-hook`).